# Docker container hangs on exec command

Tags: docker

Trying to execute shell commands in the docker container from localhost and  inside the container ,

```
  docker exec -i <container-id> sh -c "ls -l"
```

also tried `docker exec -ti <container-id> sh -c "ls -l"`

it lists the  output and keeps on hanging in the terminal .

Executed the above command by login in to the container 
It lists the output and when i  type `exit` command , it starts hanging

Server Free RAM : 3GB

```
docker logs --details <container-id>
```

returns empty output

Comment: Try `docker exec -ti <container-id> sh -c "ls -l"`

Comment: Tried the same , but still it hangs

Answer (score 18):

You need to allocate a pseudo-TTY with the `-t` option along with interactive or `-i` option. Try this:

```
$ docker exec -ti <container-id> sh -c "ls -l"
```

Comment: $ docker exec -ti <container-id> bash
Try this command and then execute the other commands. Please provide details about your image and exact command to run it if still hangs.

Comment: try this https://superuser.com/questions/1316393/why-docker-always-hangs-when-trying-to-access-container

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. I was passing a step-by-step docker tutorial. Was using Visual Studio 2022. In step-by-step tutorial worked fine.

When I tried myself docker exec command hanged.

The reason of the issue was that I used built in Visual Studio package manager console. But for running docker commands one should specifically start powershell console from the context menu of the solution.

For details you can visit [this link](https://www.mike-prog-blog.net/docker-tips-and-tricks/)

Answer (score 0):

Kind of similar happened for me too. Was using Phpstorm terminal and it hanged. Restarted server - nothing.
Only complete reboot of phpstorm helped...